# Windows 10, Datatable install issue 'Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.'

Tags: python, datatable, pip, windows-10, pyproject.toml

I have Python 3.10.2, pip 22.0.3, and pyqt5.15.2 . I run into this error when I try to install datatable:

```
pip install datatable
Collecting datatable
  Using cached datatable-1.0.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
```

I have tried building datatable from source, uninstalling and reinstalling pip along with multiple different python versions (3.8 and higher), and a good amount of time looking through datatable documentation and github issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i just installed `datatable` with pip no problem, seems like it wasnt even building a wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for python 3.10 will be in the Release 1.1.0; see https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/3210.

According to https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/discussions/3207 try the latest `main` from the repository:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/h2oai/datatable.git"
```

Comment: Thank you, I took another crack at it and it worked on 3.9. I may may have mistakenly been pointing to the wrong pip last night when I tried this version.

Comment: @ChipperDiglett, hi! Can you share your solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but installed using 'Install latest dev version' in the documentation as of 2022-12-10. I have python 3.11 and the latest version of vscode.

Here are the steps:

1. go to the AppVeyor link from the doc, and I then registered.
2. Under the Current build, artifacts tab, I copied url of a version I think suits me.
   https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/a068rbxg5k709ql7/artifacts/dist%2Fdatatable-1.1.0a0%2Bpr3388.2206-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
3. pip install YOUR_WHEEL_URL mentioned in the doc, replace with url.

   `$ pip install https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/a068rbxg5k709ql7/artifacts/dist%2Fdatatable-1.1.0a0%2Bpr3388.2206-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl Collecting datatable==1.1.0a0+pr3388.2206 Downloading https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/a068rbxg5k709ql7/artifacts/dist%2Fdatatable-1.1.0a0%2Bpr3388.2206-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (4.3 MB) ---------------------------------------- 4.3/4.3 MB 961.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00 Installing collected packages: datatable Successfully installed datatable-1.1.0a0+pr3388.2206`